# Cannot send data to a null TcpClient (check to see if Connect was called)”

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
{
txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
{
txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
e.ReplyLine(string.Format("Hi: {0}", e.MessageString));
});
```

I am trying to send a message using visual studio c# protocol tcp/ip. I successfuly connected to the server but when i try to send a text message from the client i get unhandled exception: System.Exception : 'Cannot send data to a null TcpClient (check to see if Connect was called)'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add more context to your code to make it a minimal example? Right now there may be problems that cannot be seen from the code you posted.

Comment: @Sabina, as others said, It is best for you to provide a completed code example if you want to solve tcp/ip problem. For example, please provide the code about client and server related to your problem.